# pie chart in react apexchart not getting updated when passing values dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pie chart is not getting updated when values are passed dynamically. I have passed chart id also but there was no change. when pie chart is replaced with bar chart it is getting updated.

These are the options for pie chart:

```
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';

 const [series, setSeries]: any = useState([]);
 const [options, setOptions]: any = useState({
    chart: {
      width: 380,
      type: 'pie',
      id:props?.id,
    },
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 760,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 400,
          },
          legend: {
            
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

const setArrayofSeries = (ageChartData) => {
    const label: any = [];
    const result=ageChartData.map((res:any)=>{
      label.push(res.range);
      return Number(res.count)
    }
      );
    setSeries(result);
    setOptions({ ...options, labels: label });
  };
```

i am passing these values to another file

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.series !== prevProps.series) {
      this.setState({
        options: this.props.options,
        series: this.props.series,
        title: this.props.title,
        width: this.props.width,
        subTitile: this.props.subTitile
      });
    
    }
  }

 <Chart
   options={this.state.options}
   series={this.state.series}
   type={'pie'}
   width={this.state.width ? this.state.width : '100%'}
            
          />
```

I have tried updateSeries() method in apex chart but it is making the site slow .

I am expecting pie chart to get updated.